# How to run two foreach loop inside one html table in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, loops, foreach, foreach-loop-container

I want to show two `foreach` loop data dynamically inside one table, but the design of the table break after dynamic loop data.
My blade.php code is given below:

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Buy Rate</th>
     <th>Sell Rate</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <?php foreach($datav as $data){ ?>
     <td><?php echo $data->name; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $data->buy_rate; ?></td>
   <?php } ?>
  <?php foreach($sells as $sell){ ?>
     <td><?php echo $sell->rate; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</table>
```

My route is:

```
Route::get('/','WelcomeController@test');
```

My Controller Code:

```
public function test(){

$datav= DB::table('localcurrency')
              ->where('status',1)
              ->get();
$sells= DB::table('localcurrency2')
              ->where('status',1)
              ->distinct()
              ->get();

return view('home.home_content')
        ->with('datav',$datav)
        ->with('sells',$sells);
```

}

How can I run this?

Comment: Put the `</tr>` outside of the second `foreach`.

Comment: You're potentially going to have to merge the arrays together. Please can you show your route/controller code? Are `$datav` and `$sells` arrays or collections? Also, is this in a `.blade.php` file?

Comment: Are these datasets linked somehow?

Comment: @ross-wilson i share my route, controller and .blade page code.

Comment: why don't you use @foreach construction ?

Comment: @ilya-kolesnikov i use foreach loop it broke the table structure. Can you please show me a sample, that work without breaking html table structure after loop dynamic data.

Comment: So you just want to see for each row in `$datav` all the same values from `$sells`? Like "Test 1",20,90,1000 then "Test 2",55,90,1000? How you have it all the last values will be the same in every row.

Comment: @nerdlyist currently i just want to to take value inside a single Html table from two separate table1 = localcurrency & localcurrency2. can you solve this first issue? This two table having same currency1_id & currency2_id.

Comment: In order to solve this problem there needs to be an understanding of the end result which means what do you want to see (what is wrong with it now) and what is the data structure (how does that fit into the end result). You have not provided this so coming up with an answer for you is not easy. My assumption is you really want a join on say `$data->id` on `$sells->buy_id` but you are trying to solve the display first which will not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better if you merge both $datav and $sells in one array.

In this above scenario firstly your $datav array will complete then it goes to second array.

So it will not create a complete table. Or the table alignment will be wrong.

Rest depends on what you proceed in the array.

```
public function test(){

$datav= DB::table('localcurrency')
          ->where('status',1)
          ->get();
$sells= DB::table('localcurrency2')
          ->where('status',1)
          ->distinct()
          ->get();
$sells=$sells->toArray();
$results=array();
foreach($datav as $key=>$data)
{
   $newarr=array();
   $newarr['name']=$data->name;
   $newarr['buy_rate']=$data->buy_rate;
   $newarr['sell_rate']=$sells[$key]->rate;
   $results[]=$newarr;
}
return view('home.home_content')
    ->with('results',$result);

}
```

Your views looks like this

```
<table>
   <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Buy Rate</th>
    <th>Sell Rate</th>
   </tr>
   @foreach($results as $result)
     <tr>
         <td>{{$result['name']}}</td>
         <td>{{$result['buy_rate']}}</td>
         <td>{{$result['sell_rate']}}</td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
```

Comment: can you please show me the sample code for two loop?

Comment: This is more of a comment then it is an answer. Show how you would approach the situation.

Comment: Now check my updated answer. @ner  Earlier user have not mention the controller code

Answer (score 0):

- you better to use Blade template engine syntax `@foreach($values as $value)  {{$value}} @endforeach`
- you better understand what structure of output you want to get
- your task is not resolved in this case because if you want to fill
  one table row by row by some data, this data should be interconnected
  one to one relationship, so you should do it inside of one cycle
- you can't fill first every values of first two columns of table and
  then another column's values. Table should be filled row by row